# In Bootstrap, how do I place links that are outside of the Navbar, inside the mobile Navbar only? (without having to write them twice in the HTML)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap.

I have links that are outside of the Navbar.

```
</nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<ul>
```

I also have the same links inside the Navbar, but with a "visible-xs" class attached, so that they only appear inside the Mobile Navbar. (with hamburger toggle icon menu)

```
<ul class="visible-xs">
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="outside-link">Outside Link</a></li>
<ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My current code works the way I would like, however, I do not want to write out the HTML links twice.
http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/yJeqjz

How do I place the outside links, inside ONLY the Mobile Navbar, without having to write the links twice in the HTML?

---

Ultimately, I would like these "outside links" to show on Desktop, *outside of the navbar*.

For Mobile, they will be, essentially, "moved" *inside the navbar*.

Comment: I get that you don't want to write HTML twice, but that's the whole point of `visible-xs`, for example. Sometimes, especially with navigation, you have to do that (write it twice). Otherwise, write some `jQuery` to move the links inside the `nav` on `resize event`.

Comment: See, but the problem is, my links are not supposed to be inside the Navbar on desktop-view. Only on mobile-view. If there is a jQuery solution, could you point me in the right direction? I wouldn't know where to look, in that case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS and the right HTML structure. Seperate your outside links from your standard links using `navbar-right`, then use `position: absolute` inside a media query so they are only out of the navbar above 767px.

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .ul-outside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Working Example I

```css
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .ul-outside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ul-outside">
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<!--DEMO CONTENT-->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      Outer Links
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<!--DEMO CONTENT-->
```

Working Example II:

```css
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .ul-outside {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .ul-outside > li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ul-outside">
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Outside</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<!--DEMO CONTENT-->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      Outer Links
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<!--DEMO CONTENT-->
```